# What is causing a timeout when trying to write to a Mongo replica set?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongo-shell

I am running a C# script to perform write operations to a sharded cluster.
Whenever I try to perform a write operation to the database, I get an error starting with

**A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector**

Does anyone know what I need to do in order to write successfully?  This cluster is a 3-node replicaset with one primary and two secondaries.

Here are the details:
I'm using Nuget packages: Mongo.Db.Core, Mongodb.Core.Driver and MongoDb.Bson all with version number 2.11.2. If I run db.version() in the console it returns 4.2.9

**I prepare my connection string as shown:**

```
MongoUrlBuilder bldr = new MongoUrlBuilder();
List<MongoServerAddress> servers = new List<MongoServerAddress>();

servers.Add(new MongoServerAddress("the-domain0.azure.mongodb.net", 27017));

servers.Add(new MongoServerAddress("the-domain1.azure.mongodb.net", 27017));

servers.Add(new MongoServerAddress("the-domain2.azure.mongodb.net", 27017));

bldr.Username = "the_user";
bldr.Password = "the_password";
bldr.Servers = servers;
bldr.DatabaseName = "the_db_name";

bldr.ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.ReplicaSet;

_mongoConnectionString = bldr.ToMongoUrl().ToString();
```

**I then pass it to the the client constructor as shown:**

```
    var client = new MongoClient(_mongoConnectionString);
    IMongoDatabase database = client.GetDatabase("the_db_name");
    _the_collection_name = database.GetCollection<CollType>(_collname);
```

**Everything runs fine until I need to perform this statement (an upsert)**

```
var updateResult = _the_collection_name.UpdateOne(filter, update, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });
```

**Here is the main aspect of the error:**

> System.TimeoutException: 'A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a
> server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors =
> MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector,
> LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000
> } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode
> : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers :
> [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint :
> "Unspecified/the_domain.azure.mongodb.net:27017"
> }", EndPoint:
> "Unspecified/the_domain.azure.mongodb.net:27017",
> ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: ,
> TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException:
> "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while
> opening a connection to the server.

**Here is the complete stack trace:**

> System.TimeoutException: 'A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a
> server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors =
> MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector,
> LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000
> } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode
> : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers :
> [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint :
> "Unspecified/the-domain0.azure.mongodb.net:27017"
> }", EndPoint:
> "Unspecified/the-domain0.azure.mongodb.net:27017",
> ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: ,
> TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException:
> "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while
> opening a connection to the server.  --->
> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while
> receiving a message from the server.  --->
> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the
> stream.    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.ReadBytesAsync(Stream
> stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, TimeSpan timeout,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveMessageAsync(Int32
> responseTo, IMessageEncoderSelector encoderSelector,
> MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingQueryMessageWireProtocol`1.ExecuteAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.IsMasterHelper.GetResultAsync(IConnection connection, CommandWireProtocol`1 isMasterProtocol, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.InitializeConnectionAsync(IConnection
> connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.InitializeConnectionAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)", LastHeartbeatTimestamp:
> "2020-09-11T18:25:25.7998117Z", LastUpdateTimestamp:
> "2020-09-11T18:25:25.7998118Z" }, { ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1,
> EndPoint :
> "Unspecified/the-domain1.azure.mongodb.net:27017"
> }", EndPoint:
> "Unspecified/the-domain1.azure.mongodb.net:27017",
> ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: ,
> TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException:
> "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while
> opening a connection to the server.  --->
> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while
> receiving a message from the server.  --->
> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the
> stream.    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.ReadBytesAsync(Stream
> stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, TimeSpan timeout,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveMessageAsync(Int32
> responseTo, IMessageEncoderSelector encoderSelector,
> MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingQueryMessageWireProtocol`1.ExecuteAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.IsMasterHelper.GetResultAsync(IConnection connection, CommandWireProtocol`1 isMasterProtocol, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.InitializeConnectionAsync(IConnection
> connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.InitializeConnectionAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)", LastHeartbeatTimestamp:
> "2020-09-11T18:25:25.7920423Z", LastUpdateTimestamp:
> "2020-09-11T18:25:25.7920425Z" }, { ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1,
> EndPoint :
> "Unspecified/the-domain2.azure.mongodb.net:27017"
> }", EndPoint:
> "Unspecified/the-domain2.azure.mongodb.net:27017",
> ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: ,
> TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException:
> "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while
> opening a connection to the server.  --->
> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while
> receiving a message from the server.  --->
> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the
> stream.    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.ReadBytesAsync(Stream
> stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, TimeSpan timeout,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveMessageAsync(Int32
> responseTo, IMessageEncoderSelector encoderSelector,
> MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingQueryMessageWireProtocol`1.ExecuteAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.IsMasterHelper.GetResultAsync(IConnection connection, CommandWireProtocol`1 isMasterProtocol, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.InitializeConnectionAsync(IConnection
> connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.InitializeConnectionAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)", LastHeartbeatTimestamp:
> "2020-09-11T18:25:25.5936678Z", LastUpdateTimestamp:
> "2020-09-11T18:25:25.5936680Z" }] }.'

Comment: which server/client version? I assume that any other operation like insert also throws this error?

Comment: @dododo I'm using Nuget packages: Mongo.Db.Core, Mongodb.Core.Driver and MongoDb.Bson all with version number 2.11.2.  If I run db.version() in the console it returns 4.2.9

Comment: has this code worked before for example with previous driver versions?

Comment: @dododo I wouldn't know, this is the first time I've tried it.

Comment: can you check let's say driver 2.10?

Comment: @dododo just tried it with all nuget packages at version 2.10.0.  Same result, same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221351/discussion-between-extranomical-and-dododo).

Comment: Follow everything in https://github.com/p-mongo/mongodb-faq#connectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add UseTls and change DatabaseName like below:

```
        bldr.DatabaseName = "admin";
        bldr.UseTls = true;
```